# VBA-Excel, to check parameter after certain number of iteration

Tags: vba, excel

my current problem

1. fx=(a+b)/2
2. a=fx or b=fx based on a condition
3. goes back to 1.
4. fx=(a-b)/2

i need to use function no.4 instead of 1. if either a or b does not change its value for 2 successive loops, how do i add that continuous check?

here is my code below to represent my problem above

-----------------code------------------------------

```
Sub FalsePosition()

Dim iter, es, fxl, fxu, fxr, xrold
Dim xl, xu, xr, ea, imax
Sheets("Roots").Activate
xl = Range("e3").Value 
xu = Range("e4").Value
Range("e6:e7").Clear
ea = 0.000001 'target error
imax = 1000   'maximum number of iteration
iter = 0
fxl = One(xl)  'one() is a function
fxu = One(xu)
xrold = xl + (xu - xl) / 3
    Do
    iter = iter + 1

    xr = xu - fxu * (xl - xu) / (fxl - fxu) ' false position method

    fxr = One(xr)

    If xr = 0 Then ' to calculate estimated error
        es = Abs(xr - xrold)
    Else
        es = Abs((xr - xrold) / xr)
    End If
```

' if fxr and fxu have different signs, replace lower bound

```
    If fxr * fxu < 0 Then
        xl = xr
        fxl = fxr
        Range("e3").Value = xl
    Else ' replace upper bound
        xu = xr
        fxu = fxr
        Range("e4").Value = xu
    End If
    xrold = xr
    Delay (0.25)
Loop While iter < imax And es > ea
```

---

I need to use another method(equation) to replace false position method if either xu or xl value did not change for every 2 successive loops. how do i add that check?

Comment: that doesn't look much like code to me, can you post up your actual code please?

Comment: -1, since you didn't post any code and didn't react to requests for it. And please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i apologize, i've updated the post. im fairly new in vba (like a week old), tryin to solve math problems on vba. i manage to do step 1 to 3 which works, i could not figure out how to add the 4th.

Answer (score 0):

Without having any code provided by you, my guess is that you could use a help-column:

(1) Start Module

(2) Write Initial values for a and b into cells X1 and X2

(3) Let iterations go through

(4) Write last Iteration in cells Z1 and Z2

`If X1 <> Z1 Then
    'Your code
End If
If X2 <> Z2 Then
    'Your code
End If`

The same could be done for all iterations, always posting them in successive order.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
For Each cell In rng
    'test if cell is empty
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        'write to adjacent cell
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Value of A
    End If
Next
```

And the same for the value of B.

Answer (score 0):

Use VBA Modulus operator `MOD` to return the remainder of `Iterations/Target Number of Iterations`.  If the remainder is `0` then execute the code.

---

```
Sub TestModIterations()
    Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To 20

        If (x Mod 2) = 0 Then
            Debug.Print x; " Modulus 2 ="; (x Mod 2)
        End If

        If (x Mod 4) = 0 Then
            Debug.Print x; " Modulus 4 ="; (x Mod 4)
        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

---

[image]